# Generic struct from defined protocol

Tags: swift, generics

I know this may sound basic to a lot of people, but my brain today is working at 2 cylinders and I cannot figure this out...

I had this view working perfectly.

```
struct MyView: View {

  @ObservedObject private var myModel:MyModel
  
  init(myModel:MyModel) {
    self.myModel = myModel
  }
```

Now I have a second kind of model. I need to modify `MyView` to be generic.

So I have started by creating a protocol because the variables and function calls of both models will be the same and assigned these protocols to both models.

Now I need to modify the view to something like

```
struct MyView: View {

  @ObservedObject private var myModel:Any
  
  init(myModel:Any) {
    self.myModel = myModel
  }
```

But I am sure it is not the way to do that.

or something like

```
struct MyView<T>: View {

  @ObservedObject private var myModel:T
  
  init(myModel:T) {
    self.myModel = myModel
  }
```

but I cannot figure out the exact syntax.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're just missing the requirement that `T` be an ObservableObject:

```
struct MyView<T: ObservableObject>: View { ... }
```

Comment: Brilliant. I love how Xcode is a total and complete failure, unable to give any sensible clue. Thank you very much! Cannot upvote you enough.